# Phonegap Emulator Error - 'emulate android' is not a phonegap command

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, phonegap-build, mobile-application

When I execute the following command in the terminal:
phonegap emulate android

I am getting the following error:

[error] 'emulate android' is not a phonegap command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that phonegap cli has less and less commands at each new version.

Either run `phonegap run android` which should look for a device and start the emulator if none is found

or install the cordova cli and then use `cordova emulate android`